# Realm file could not be opened

Tags: realm

When I use realm for Android 0.82.2 I can open default.realm file in Realm Browser 0.95.2 (9).  But when I use realm 0.83.0 and try to open default.ream in Browser I get an error:

> 'default' could not be opened. It may be encrypted, or it isn't in a compatible file format.

I don't use encryption. Realm browser installed from App Store.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Realm Java 0.83 brings a [breaking change to the file format](https://realm.io/news/realm-java-0.83.0/).

<del>This wasn't adopted yet by the browser. But there is a [branch with still experimental support for nullable properties](https://github.com/realm/realm-browser-osx/tree/0.96-beta), which you would need to compile yourself for now. Sorry for the inconvenience at this place, we're working on that.</del>

#### Update:

The latest release is available on the AppStore and [precompiled on GitHub](https://github.com/realm/realm-browser-osx/releases/latest) as well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll wait for the release version of the browser 8)

Comment: is this fixed now? because I am getting the same error. I am using latest Realm version (0.84.1) and Realm browser

Comment: I updated my answer. The last recent version has found its way to the AppStore and updated binaries are up on GitHub.

Comment: This solution worked perfectly. My Realm browser was simply out of date. Updated via App Store and is working like a charm.