# 'default' could not be opened. It may be encrypted, or it isn't in a compatible file format

Tags: android, macos, realm

This error is showing when trying to open default.realm with the Realm Browser after pulling it from an emulator device.

This warning is being shown after the adb command:

> adb: warning: skipping special file
>   '/data/data/com.app.myapp/files/default.realm.management/access_control.new_commit.cv'
>   (mode = 0o10600) /data/data/com.app.myapp/files/: 13 files pulled. 1
>   file skipped. 0.0 MB/s (30377 bytes in 1.455s)

- Command: *adb -s emulator-5556 pull /data/data/com.app.myapp/files/ .*
- MAC OS X EL Capitan 10.11.6
- Realm Browser Version 0.103.2 (76)
- Realm version 1.2.0
- Emulator: Galaxy Nexus API 17 JB

Error message:

> 'default' could not be opened. It may be encrypted, or it isn't in a
>   compatible file format.
>
> If you know the file is encrypted, you can manually enter its
>   encryption key to open it.

Does anyone has any idea how to solve this problem?
It seems it already happened in a previous version: [Realm file could not be opened](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33127134/realm-file-could-not-be-opened)

Comment: Does your app encrypt the Realm database? Did you create the Realm with options others than defaults? You're pulling the DB from the emulator, so, Are you sure the app is not performing a transaction while you're copying the .realm file?

Comment: Make sure the Realm is closed before getting it from the emulator.

Comment: I'm using the default RealmConfiguration with the addition of `deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()`. I've closed the app before performing the adb command. All the writing queries are being performed inside a `Realm.getDefaultInstance().executeTransaction` block and all the reading are surrounded by a `Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();` and `realm.close();`.

Comment: Can you share your `default.realm` with us? you can send it to help@realm.io

Comment: email sent @beeender

Comment: It seems fine with the latest realm-browser (1.0.2), can you please try it? https://github.com/realm/realm-browser-osx/releases/tag/1.0.2

Comment: @beeender work like a charm. Thank you!